# I'm having a problem with creating a lexer using PLY in Python

Tags: python, ply

I have tried to create a Lexer recently, and it doesn't work out well.

The problem is it's thrown an error message shows that "Can't build lexer". Here's the traceback:

```
ERROR: Rule 't_TIMES' defined for an unspecified token TIMES
ERROR: Rule 't_DIVIDE' defined for an unspecified token DIVIDE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Lexer.py", line 24, in <module>
    lexer = lex.lex()
            ^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\lex.py", line 910, in lex
    raise SyntaxError("Can't build lexer")
SyntaxError: Can't build lexer
```

I'm aware that it's because of the `t_error()` function of mine. I also sense the token I've made maybe having a problem. Please help me with that, I know that this is kind of dumb but I'm new, so please be nice to me.
Btw, here's the source code

```py
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

import sys

tokens = [
    "INT",
    "ID",
    "PLUS",
    "MINUS",
    "EOF",
]

t_INT = r"\d+"
t_ID = r"[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*"
t_PLUS = r"+"
t_MINUS = r"-"
t_TIMES = r"*"
t_DIVIDE = r"/"

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.lexer.lexeme, file=sys.stderr)

lexer = lex.lex()

def p_expression(p):
    """expression : INT
                 | ID
                 | expression PLUS expression
                 | expression MINUS expression
                 | expression TIMES expression
                 | expression DIVIDE expression"""
    if len(p) == 2:
        if isinstance(p[1], int):
            p[0] = p[1]
        elif isinstance(p[1], str):
            p[0] = p[1]
    else:
        if p[2] == "+":
            p[0] = p[1] + p[3]
        elif p[2] == "-":
            p[0] = p[1] - p[3]
        elif p[2] == "*":
            p[0] = p[1] * p[3]
        elif p[2] == "/":
            p[0] = p[1] / p[3]

parser = yacc.yacc()

def test(text):
    try:
        result = parser.parse(text)
        if result:
            print(result)
        else:
            print("Empty expression")
    except yacc.YaccError:
        print("Error parsing input")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test("123")
    test("hello")
    test("123 + 456")
    test("123 - 456")
    test("123 * 456")
    test("123 / 456")
```

Maybe I'm just stupid, but because of that so I cannot make it to run.

Comment: In what way is this not working? If you're getting a specific error message, please include that in your question (along with a complete traceback if one is generated).

Comment: oh i forgot to mention that the problem is the lexer can't be build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors...

```
ERROR: Rule 't_TIMES' defined for an unspecified token TIMES
ERROR: Rule 't_DIVIDE' defined for an unspecified token DIVIDE
```

...seem pretty clear. You haven't defined the tokens named `TIMES` or `DIVIDE` in your `tokens` array. You need:

```
tokens = [
    "INT",
    "ID",
    "PLUS",
    "MINUS",
    "EOF",
    "TIMES",
    "DIVIDE",
]
```

Once you fix those errors, you will get:

```
ERROR: Invalid regular expression for rule 't_PLUS'. nothing to repeat at position 11
ERROR: Invalid regular expression for rule 't_TIMES'. nothing to repeat at position 12
```

That's because the characters `+` and `*` are both regex wildcards, so you need to escape them if you want the literal character:

```
t_PLUS = r"\+"
t_TIMES = r"\*"
```

Once you fix *those* errors, you'll ultimately get this from your `t_error` method:

```
AttributeError: 'Lexer' object has no attribute 'lexeme'. Did you mean: 'lexre'?
```

There doesn't appear to be a `lexeme` attribute, but you can  use `t.value`:

```
def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value, file=sys.stderr)
```

Having fixed that error, you will now get:

```
123
hello
Illegal character ' + 456'
.
.
.
ply.lex.LexError: Scanning error. Illegal character ' '
```

You have spaces in your expressions, but you haven't accounted for this in your rules. The quick fix is to remove the spaces in your test expressions:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test("123")
    test("hello")
    test("123+456")
    test("123-456")
    test("123*456")
    test("123/456")
```

Having fixed that error, you'll now get:

```
123
hello
123456
.
.
.
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

And that's because you're trying to add string values in your `p_expression` method. You need to convert them to numbers before applying arithmetic operators. The easiest solution is to replace your definition of `t_INT` with this method:

```
def t_INT(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t
```

And now running the code produces:

```
123
hello
579
-333
56088
0.26973684210526316
```